# Rotate to 180Degrees HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
#prop1 {
border-top: 10px solid #99B898; 
border-bottom: 10px solid #FECEA8; 
border-left: 10px solid #FF847C; 
border-right: 10px solid #E84A5F; 
background-color: black;
width: 0px;
height: 220px;
position: relative;
   float: left;
       transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-1800deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */    
  padding: 0px; /* if you want space between the images */
}
```

```html
<div id="prop1">
</div>
<div id="prop1">
</div>
<div id="prop1">
</div>
<div id="prop1">
</div>
```

Can anyone help me here?

This is what i'm having trouble with, I want it to rotate (-180)degrees like what 
i have shown here below, i've tried doing it but it has not worked, so like no effect or anything.`

```
transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-1800deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

`
I want something like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6L5T.png)

Comment: Your divs are already rotated -180 degree... that is vertical flip

Comment: How do I get it to be horizontal?

Comment: can you describe exactly how you want.. pls update your question....if you want horizontal, try rotating it by 90degree

Comment: I think I edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a wrapper and rotate it instead of inner divs.

see below snippet.

```css
#prop1 {
  border-top: 10px solid #99B898; 
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FECEA8; 
  border-left: 10px solid #FF847C; 
  border-right: 10px solid #E84A5F; 
  background-color: black;
  width: 0px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px; /* if you want space between the images */
}

#main {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */ 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="prop1">
  </div>
  <div id="prop1">
  </div>
  <div id="prop1">
  </div>
  <div id="prop1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* IE 9 */ -- added extra "0"
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

-- your css is proper. you can try "`transform: rotate(180deg)`;"